# Issue with Azure Event Hubs creation of 1 Hub

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I have an issue when I am trying to create a new event hub in azure.
Should be able to create only 1 instance with 1 partition only. However, the process does not let me proceed.

Two issues:

-Impossible to create one hub with one partition (min 2 proposed)

-Impossible to generate de hub (error of ID and charge in relation)

Did you ever get the same issue

[New EventHub 2 partitions min](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXhtf.jpg)

[ID problem when commit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucaef.jpg)

Comment: May you be using a Basic SKU namespace by any chance? Can you try with Standard if so?

Comment: No SKU namespace. I create the Hub directly through web interface

Answer (score 0):

I tried with an account having more credentials and it worked. The free version of azure does not allow to create an event hub it seems...